# Select Statement To Retrieve Same Column Twice

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I Have 2 tables:

Table 1 named **category_desription**, it contains 2 fields: **category_name** and **category_id**.

Table 2 named **category** includes the **category_id** and **parent_Category_id** fields which are foreign keys from **category_id** in the first table.

I want to select 4 fields whereby the result will contain  **category_id** and its name **category_name** and **parent_category_id** and its name as well which happens to be **category_name** as well

I couldn't figure out how to do it so far so I wish if someone assist me in this.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as well formatted text. Also show us your current query attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this will solve your prblm

```
SELECT  category_id, 
(Select category_name from table1 where category_id= table2.category_id) as category_name , 
parent_category_id, 
(Select category_name from table1 where category_id= table2.parent_category_id) 
as parent_category_name from table2
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple name conflict issue in SQL, which can be solved easily by using `alias`

e.g.

```
Select t1.category_id, t1.category_name, t2.category_id, t2.category_name
from table1 t1 join table2 t2 on <some condition..>
```

You can also give different names to the result column

```
 Select t1.category_id, t1.category_name as 'Parent Category Name',
 t2.category_id, t2.category_name as 'Category Name'
 from table1 t1 join table2 t2 on <some condition..>
```

I hope it solves your issue.

Comment: downvote because category_name is not second table field

Comment: @DarshakGajjar this is just to explain OP the concept of `alias`. Providing an exact solution was never an intent.

Comment: :-  if you explain OP concept then you can simply comment of question as suggestion..

Answer (score 0):

```
 with category_desc as
 (select 1 as category_id, 'Category 1' as category_name
    from dual
  union all
  select 2 as category_id, 'Category 2' as category_name from dual),
category as
 (select 1 as category_id, 2 as parent_category_id from dual)
select c.category_id,
       c_d.category_name,
       c.parent_category_id,
       pc_d.category_name parent_category_name
  from category c
  join category_desc c_d
    on c_d.category_id = c.category_id
  join category_desc pc_d
    on pc_d.category_id = c.parent_category_id
```

use category_desc with different alias to find parent_category details